# how can I compare an instance of a class with a char * variable in c++?

Tags: c++, char, compare, instance

I need help on my homework assignment.I need to write the code for a parking garage. and in order to write it I need to copare the input of my instance of the class"`Parkbox`",which has been created on the on the heap and via another class "Parkinggarage" , with a `#define EMPTY "--------".`
So this is my code:
the Parkbox definition:

```
class Parkbox{
char *license_plate; // car's license plate

public:
Parkbox(); //Default CTOR
Parkbox(char * ); // CTOR
~Parkbox(); // DTOR
void show();
};
and ParkingGarage:
class ParkingGarage{
Parkbox ***p2parkboxes;
```

and my CTOR or ParkingGarage in order to create Parkbox instance on the heap:

```
ParkingGarage::ParkingGarage(const int rw,const int clm, const int plns){

        p2parkboxes = new Parkbox **[plns];//points to the floors and make the arraq of p2p same size as number as floors
        for(int p=0;p<plns;p++){
            p2parkboxes[p]= new Parkbox *[plns];//for each Plane creats an array of pointer that is same with the num of rows
            for(int r=0;r<rw;r++)
                p2parkboxes[p][r]= new Parkbox [clm];
        }
    }

void ParkingGarage::find_next_free_parking_position()
{
    for(int f=0;f<dimensions_of_parkhouse[0];f++){
        for(int r=0;r<dimensions_of_parkhouse[1];r++){
            for (int c=0;c<dimensions_of_parkhouse[2];c++){ 
                //p2parkboxes[f][r][c] is the instance of the class Pakbox
                if(p2parkboxes[f][r][c]==EMPTY)
                {
                    next_free_parking_position[0]=p;
                    next_free_parking_position[1]=r;
                    next_free_parking_position[2]=c;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how ever at the point "`p2parkboxes[f][r][c]==EMPTY`" it gives me error that " no operator "==" matches these operands", .
then how can I compare a class instance directly with another variables like EMPTY?

I do not know if I am clear for you or not. 
But please help me because if I do not solve this problem I can not continue completing my code.

Comment: Can you post the definition of the type of `p2parkboxes[f][r][c]`?

Comment: yes this is declaring it: class ParkingGarage{
                          Parkbox ***p2parkboxes;                       and I created the object in the CTOR og parkinggarage:  ParkingGarage::ParkingGarage(const int rw,const int clm, const int plns){
 p2parkboxes = new Parkbox **[plns];//points to the floors    and make the arraq of p2p same size as number as floors
 for(int p=0;p<plns;p++){
  p2parkboxes[p]= new Parkbox *[plns];//for each Plane creats an array of pointer that is same with the num of rows
  for(int r=0;r<rw;r++)
   p2parkboxes[p][r]= new Parkbox [clm];
 }
}

Comment: this is the Parkbox class header:                                       class Parkbox{
char *license_plate; // car's license plate
public:
Parkbox(); //Default CTOR
Parkbox(char * ); // CTOR
~Parkbox(); // DTOR
void show();
};

Comment: You can edit your original question with the code you posted in the comments.

Comment: It's difficult to help if we don't know what is allowed.  The only way to compare class instance is by operator oveloading, so if this is not allowed, you should probably make a getter function and compare its result: `strcmp(p2parkboxes[f][r][c].getPlate(), EMPTY)`.  Hopefully you'll get to containers and stings soon, because now, you're not really learning c++.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can only compare two same types. With operator overloading, you can define your own compare operator to work with this problem. C++ cannot compare two classes in default though.

So it seems in your code that you are comparing char* type with your class type. You should compare char* with another char*. If it's treated as string, you should use strcmp for increased safety

Comment: Comparing pointers is usually not a good idea (unless you really want to compare pointers, not the value they're pointing to).

Comment: So what is the solution in here. I am working on this part now for 4 days and I could not find a way for it :(.

Comment: Mario, that's true. Somehow it does work in simple situations at least in msvc++. Dunno if that's standard, though. mrmrk You should try it out yourself. You won't learn anything if you just copypaste code.

Comment: Weggo thank you for your hint, but I do not expect direct answer, just suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a matching operator overload. The compiler error should name you the parameters, but the member should most likely look a bit like the following:

```
bool Pakbox::operator==(const char *other) {
    return !strcmp(other, this->memberstring);
}
```

Note that `memberstring` has to be replaced by an actual member holding what's in that lot.

Comment: But we are not allow to use string class in here, the only thing we can use are stcpy and strlen and we haven´t studied operator overload or this yes, so we are not allowed to use them neither, any other ways?

Comment: @mrmrk the string class is not used here. `strcmp` works on `char*` just like `strlen` and `strcpy`.

Comment: If you need to, you could as well write your own `strcmp()` function iterating over both strings comparing characters. It's not that hard.

Comment: thank you Mario, but I have to find another solution for that because I know my prof will not accept this solution. he oes not open our hand for coding. any way thank you :)

Comment: MArio, I made it work without all these. yuhuuuuuuu. thank you for your hints though. I made a function for comparison, and I compare it via my private member variable "Licence_Plate". then in that function I made my comparison. :)